# Recommendations for MRI classification in R of large dataset (n=100, p=20000)

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, random-forest

I am working on a magnetic-resonance imaging dataset which includes about 100 observations (= subjects) and 20000 predictors (=voxels). I would like to conduct classification  in R using methods like support-vector machines or random-forests. I believe that analysis of large datasets will require special setup & would like to know about recommendations, if thats possible in R and what hardware is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

While this dataset may be "large" by MRI standards, it's nowhere near big enough to cause problems in R. Using random data of these dimensions, and the default settings, on a fairly average machine (MacBook Air, late 2011), I was able to run R's `randomForest` in 37 seconds, and `svm` (from the `e1071` package) in 6 seconds.

In general, R should be able to cope with datasets about one to three orders of magnitude larger than what you're currently working with, depending on the specific task you're trying to accomplish. If you do run into trouble, you may find that using a 64-bit version of R will help. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) on Stack Overflow also lists some tips and tricks for dealing with larger datasets.